# C# - Any clever way to get an int array from an object collection?

Tags: linq, arrays, c#-3.0, filtering, arraycollection

How can I create an easy helper method to get an int array from a collection of objects?

The idea would be have a method which receive a collection of "User" class:

```
public class User { 
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    public string UserName {get;set;}
}
```

And filter this collection to get an int array of unique UserIds.

```
List<int> repeatedUserIds = (from item in list 
                             select item.UserId).ToList();
List<int> uniqueUserIds = ((from n in repeatedUserIds 
                             select n).Distinct()).ToList();
```

Is there a way to create a clever method for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an extension method:

```
public int[] GetUniqueIds<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, int> idSelector)
{
    return items.Select(idSelector).Distinct().ToArray();
}
```

And use it like this:

```
int[] uniqueUserIds = list.GetUniqueIds(u => u.UserId);
```

Comment: extesions methods are awesome. I've adapted ToArray() to ToList(), added static keyword and it's working pretty well. Thank you Lee

Answer (score 2):

Well, I wouldn't bother with a query expression, personally - but the rest is fine:

```
List<int> repeatedUserIds = list.Select(item => item.UserId)
                                .ToList();
List<int> uniqueUserIds = repeatedUserIds.Distinct()
                                         .ToList();
```

If you don't need `repeatedUserIds` for anything else, don't bother with the intermediate call to `ToList()`:

```
List<int> uniqueUserIds = list.Select(item => item.UserId)
                              .Distinct()
                              .ToList();
```

(I generally like putting each operation on a separate line, but of course you don't have to.)

Note that your *text* asks for an array, but your *code* has been in terms of `List<int>`. If you genuinely want an `int[]` instead of a `List<int>`, just change the `ToList()` calls to `ToArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<int> uniqueUserIds = (from n in list  
                            select item.UserId).Distinct().ToList();
```